# Variable distance between header and table

Tags: tex-core

I'm using a great calendar generator [latex-calgen](https://github.com/simu/latex-calgen/) by Simon Gerber. It combines python and LaTeX to generate a pdf file with a calendar. Each month is on a separate page and every page has a **header** on top, consisting of year on the left and month name on the right. Below the **header** is **table** with numbered days for a given month.

The little annoyance, I would like to fix (but don't know how) is the perception of variable distance between the **header** and the **table**. If the month name contains a letter 'p', 'y' or 'g' eg. 'April', the **table** appears to be placed slightly lower than the table for 'March'. I do appreciate the fact that distance is actually the same as it is calculated from the bottom of letter 'p'. Nevertheless, the perception is that for 'April' the distance between **table** and **header** is greater than the same distance for 'March'.

I would like to change the LaTeX part of latex-calgen [head.tex.in](https://github.com/simu/latex-calgen/blob/master/head.tex.in) so that the distance between **header** and **table** appears the same. Which ironically means that the actual distance would have to be increased for month names not containing letters 'p', 'y' or 'g'.

[image: March is closer to the table]
[image: Letter 'p' in April pushes the table lower]

The code responsible for generating the **header** looks like this:

```
\newsavebox\TBox
\sbox\TBox{2022}

% month heading design
\newcommand{\monthhead}[2]{%
{\hspace{-6mm}\resizebox{!}{\wd\TBox}{%
#2}\hfill\resizebox{!}{\wd\TBox}{#1}\\[1mm]}}
```

I'm out of my depth here so would appreciate any pointers on how I could achieve the appearance of the same **header** to **table** distance. Adding an invisible letter 'p' in front of each month's name would be acceptable :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can place `\strut` directly after or before `#2` and directly after or before `#1`.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you :)